# Update class of a component from a different component in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I'm trying to update a class of a element available in'sidebar' component when a button is clicked which is available in a different component named 'header'

My current setup:

**app.ts**

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <app-header></app-header>
      <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
    </div>
  `,
})
```

**header.ts**

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  template: '<header><button (click)="isActiveSidebar = false">close aside</button></header>'
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  isActiveSidebar = true;
}
```

**sidebar.ts**

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  template: '<aside [class.aside-hidden]="!isActiveSidebar">sidbar</aside>'
})
```

**Plunkr**
https://plnkr.co/edit/7iTE8Nb4R0TbUqhYv3QG?p=preview

What I was expecting here, when I clicked the button in header component, the property `isActiveSidebar` would set to false and the `aside` element in sidebar component would a get the class '`aside-hidden`'

Same kind of setup worked for me when I'm using the same inside one single component. Currently I have no idea on how to get this done between 2 different component. I would really appreciate if you could help me on this by updating the given plunkr demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `@Output()` in the `HeaderComponent` and wire it up with the sidebar:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  template: '<header><button (click)="deactivate()">close aside</button></header>'
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() deactivateSidebar:EventEmitter<bool> = new EventEmitter<bool>();
  isActiveSidebar = true;

  deactivate() {
    this.isActiveSidebar = false;
    this.deactivateSidebar.emit(null);
  }
}
```

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <app-header (deactivateSidebar)="sidebar.deactivate()"></app-header>
      <app-sidebar #sidebar></app-sidebar>
    </div>
  `,
})
```

```ts
class AppSidebarComponent {
  deactivate() {
    this.isActiveSidebar = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Here <app-sidebar #sidebar></app-sidebar> what does #sidebar means?

Comment: It's a template variable. In case of a plain HTML element, it creates a reference to the element, in case of a component, it creates a reference to the component instance. I use it to access the sidebar component in `(deactivateSidebar)="sidebar. ..."`

Comment: Where should I put the 'class AppSidebarComponent...' can you please update my plunkr.

Comment: That was just an assumption how you sidebar components class is named.

Comment: I've tried this but no luck. Can you please check my updated plunkr? https://plnkr.co/edit/7iTE8Nb4R0TbUqhYv3QG?p=preview

Comment: There is a weird error in the Plunker (`Invalid regular expression: missing /`) no idea where it comes from. Did you starte with the Plunker Angular2 template?) I forgot a change - sorry - I updated the `HeaderComponent` https://plnkr.co/edit/l63AsOwCOJUnrB1qotCr?p=preview

Comment: That was because of missing template and selector in sidebar component. I've fixed it but now ended up with a new error 'Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the module 'AppModule''

https://plnkr.co/edit/l63AsOwCOJUnrB1qotCr?p=preview

Comment: The class name is `AppSidebarComponent` instead of `SidebarComponent` https://plnkr.co/edit/l63AsOwCOJUnrB1qotCr?p=preview

Comment: Awesome! Why it has to be this complicated to access another component's property in angular2? Why can't they make it something like anothercomponent.isActiveSidebar = false or something like it was in original angular. May be i'm too fresh to understand these logic. Either way, it works and thank you very much.

Comment: There is a tutorial about component communication https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html. There are several reasons. Mostly for reducing complexity of Angular for better performance and to be able to do AoT compilation.